# ImportError: No module named 'version' during installation

Tags: python, import, module, installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install SMOP on Anaconda3 (Python 3.5.1), but it fails due to the following error:

```
[Anaconda3] C:\Users\IanHacker\Downloads\smop-0.29>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from smop.version import __version__
  File "C:\Users\IanHacker\Downloads\smop-0.29\smop\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import version
ImportError: No module named 'version'
```

"pip install smop" and "easy_install smop" return the same error.
I referred to [ImportError: No module named 'version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423793/importerror-no-module-named-version), so I changed the content of __init__.py:

```
import version
import parse,resolve,backend,main
from version import __version__
```

to:

```
__version__ = '0.29'
import parse,resolve,backend,main
```

... then, I got:

```
[Anaconda3] C:\Users\IanHacker\Downloads\smop-0.29>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from smop.version import __version__
  File "C:\Users\IanHacker\Downloads\smop-0.29\smop\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import parse,resolve,backend,main
ImportError: No module named 'parse'
```

I don't even know if the __version__ issue has been solved.
Even if it has been solved, I don't know what to replace "parse" with.
And ... do I have to keep replacing until this works? Is there any better way to solve this?

*For those who installed Anaconda, could you try to run the command and check if the same error happens? Am I the only one who gets this error?

Comment: SMOP does not seem to support python3. Try python2.7

Comment: @cel I've just tried python2.7, but no luck. This time, No module named **readline**
`(py27) [Anaconda3] C:\Users\IanHacker\Downloads\smop-0.29>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from smop.version import __version__
  File "C:\Users\IanHacker\Downloads\smop-0.29\smop\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import parse,resolve,backend,main
  File "C:\Users\IanHacker\Downloads\smop-0.29\smop\parse.py", line 9, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: No module named readline`