# Installation of pyinsane2 fails due to missing version module (Python 3.6 / Windows)

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I want to install pyinsane2 using Python 3.6 on Windows 8.1. When running 'python setup.py sdist_wheel install' it tells me: no module named 'version'. So I tried to install the module `version` manually.

Running the command `pip install version`, it then shows me an Import error `cannot import name 'izip_longest'`. I already know that I have to take out the i of izip in python 3, but I cannot find the file, where I can change it. 
It tells me the file (version.py) would lay in 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p619-k9v6\version\version.py', but the folder pip-build-p619-k9v6 does not exist in my Temp directory.

Any Ideas how I can get access to the file? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use the [semver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/semver) module instead?

Comment: I can't tell the diffrence, but I'm actually just installing the "version" module, because I want to install pyinsane2. When running 'python setup.py sdist_wheel install' it tells me: no module named 'version'. so I wanted to install the module version ..., But thanks for you help!

Comment: What happens if you first execute `pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools` and `pip install pyinsane2` afterwards?

Comment: so after the first command its tell me "Requirements are already up to date" and after the second command: Couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement pyinsane2 (from versions: ). No matching distribution found for pyinsane2

Comment: Which Python3 version do you use?

Comment: im using Python 3.6.3  on windows 8.1

Comment: I added an answer for what I think is the root cause of your problem. Besides, you might want to edit your answer to describe your actual problem (installation of pyinsane2), see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

`pyinsane2` only provides pre-built windows binaries for Python 3.4, as you can see [here on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinsane2/2.0.10). You are using Python 3.6. If you do not have compiler installed ([see for example this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473854/python-pip-has-issues-with-path-for-ms-visual-studio-2010-express-for-64-bit-ins)), `pip install` will fail, as `pyinsane2` requires compilation for some extension modules.

Why you are getting the error about the `version` module, I can not say. My recommendation is to install [the latest version of Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473854/python-pip-has-issues-with-path-for-ms-visual-studio-2010-express-for-64-bit-ins) and retry `pip install pyinsane2`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how the links are helping to fix my issue.

Comment: The link to PyPI shows that there are no pre-built binaries for Python 3.6. If you want to install it with Python 3.6, you need a compiler installed. As an alternative, you could install and use Python 3.4 (and install pyinsane2 with that python interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

See this previous post for an answer to your problem with the version module in Python 3.

[ImportError: No module named 'version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423793/importerror-no-module-named-version)

Comment: As it says there, I'm supposed to type "from .version import __version__" instead of just import version. But running this it tells me "No Module named: pyinsane2.version"

Comment: There may be a compatibility issue, see here:
https://github.com/openpaperwork/pyinsane/issues/41

Comment: I opened that issue haha!