# Trouble shooting when tring to install and import `stats_exporter` from `opencensus.ext.stackdriver`

Tags: python, opencensus

Im trying to install and use `stats_exporter` from `opencensus.ext.stackdriver` using the following guide: [opencensus-ext-stackdriver](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/tree/master/contrib/opencensus-ext-stackdriver)

after installing it through pip:

`pip install opencensus-ext-stackdriver`

Im trying to import it and:

```
from opencensus.ext.stackdriver import stats_exporter as stackdriver
ImportError: cannot import name 'stats_exporter' from 'opencensus.ext.stackdriver'
```

When comparing the Git repo, and my local `venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/...`   it seems like the pip version isn't compatible with Github , so i tried to install it though cloning, and using `setup.py`

```
pip install ../opencensus-python/contrib/opencensus-ext-stackdriver/dist/opencensus-ext-stackdriver-0.2.dev0.tar.gz
```

which gives me the following error:

```
(venv) Yehoshaphats-MacBook-Pro:present-value yehoshaphatschellekens$ pip install ../opencensus-python/contrib/opencensus-ext-stackdriver/dist/opencensus-ext-stackdriver-0.2.dev0.tar.gz 
Processing /Users/yehoshaphatschellekens/opencensus-python/contrib/opencensus-ext-stackdriver/dist/opencensus-ext-stackdriver-0.2.dev0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/s2/y6vcdc1105s8xlpb12slr9z00000gn/T/pip-req-build-7m1ibdpd/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        from version import __version__
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/s2/y6vcdc1105s8xlpb12slr9z00000gn/T/pip-req-build-7m1ibdpd/
```

Similar errors of this type indicated that i need to upgrade `setuptools`, tried that also :(

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423793/importerror-no-module-named-version) suggests that it might related to the fact that i'm using python3, which isn't completable with `version` though i really need to install this package on my python3 venv.

Any Help on this issue would be great!

Comment: if you need a complete example in python3, here there you can find it: https://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2020/05/tracing-with-opencensus-and-stackdriver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

from opencensus.common.transports.async_ import AsyncTransport

from opencensus.ext.stackdriver import trace_exporter as stackdriver_exporter

from opencensus.trace import tracer as tracer_module
from opencensus.stats import stats as stats_module


def main():
    sde = stackdriver_exporter.StackdriverExporter(
                project_id=os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID"),
                transport=AsyncTransport)

    tracer = tracer_module.Tracer(exporter=sde)
    with tracer.span(name='doingWork') as span:
        for i in range(10):
            continue


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and

```
grpcio==1.19.0
opencensus==0.3.1
opencensus-ext-stackdriver==0.1.1
```

**NB** The OpenCensus libraries need gRPC too.

You will need:

- a GCP Project and it's Project ID (`${PROJECT_ID}`)
- a service account with `roles/cloudtrace.agent` and its key.

Then:

```sh
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate

export PROJECT_ID=[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json

pip3 install --requirement requirements.txt
python3 stackdriver.py
```